# Working on Mern Stack Application - Update Operation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Table, Modal, Form, FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from 'axios';
import CompanyEditModal from './CompanyEditModal';

const Company = props => (
  <tr>
    <td>{props.company.companyName}</td>
    <td>{props.company.taxOffice}</td>
    <td>{props.company.taxNumber}</td>
    <td>{props.company.date}</td>
    <td>
      <Button
        variant="danger"
        onClick={() => props.onDelete(props.company._id)}
        style={{ marginRight: '20px' }}
      >
        Sil
      </Button>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => ...... TO BE DONE}>
        Edit
      </Button>
    </td>
  </tr>
);

class Companies extends React.Component {
  state = {
    companies: [],
    companyName: '',
    taxOffice: '',
    taxNumber: '',
    companyId: '',
    show: false,
    searchTerm: ''
  };

  onChange_1 = e => {
    this.setState({
      companyName: e.target.value
    });
  };
  onChange_2 = e => {
    this.setState({
      taxOffice: e.target.value
    });
  };
  onChange_3 = e => {
    this.setState({
      taxNumber: e.target.value
    });
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const company = {
      companyName: this.state.companyName,
      taxOffice: this.state.taxOffice,
      taxNumber: this.state.taxNumber
    };

    console.log(company);

    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/companies/add', company).then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
      window.location.reload();
    });

    this.setState({
      companyName: ''
    });
  };

  CompanyModal = () => {
    const handleClose = () => this.setState({ show: false });
    const handleShow = () => this.setState({ show: true });

    return (
      <>
        <Button variant="success" type="submit" onClick={handleShow}>
          + Firma Ekle
        </Button>

        <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={handleClose}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Firma Ekle</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <Form.Label>Firma Adı:</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                placeholder="* Firma Adını Giriniz"
                onChange={this.onChange_1}
                value={this.state.companyName}
              />
              <Form.Text className="text-muted">* Girmek zorunludur.</Form.Text>
              <br />
              <Form.Label>Vergi Dairesi:</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                placeholder="Vergi Dairesini Giriniz"
                onChange={this.onChange_2}
                value={this.state.taxOffice}
              />
              <br />
              <Form.Label>Vergi Numarası:</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                placeholder="Vergi Numarasını Giriniz"
                onChange={this.onChange_3}
                value={this.state.taxNumber}
              />
              <br />
              <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={handleClose}>
                Kaydet
              </Button>
              <Button variant="danger" onClick={handleClose}>
                Kapat
              </Button>
            </Form>
          </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
      </>
    );
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:5000/companies/')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ companies: response.data });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  onDelete = id => {
    axios.delete('http://localhost:5000/companies/' + id).then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
    });

    this.setState({
      companies: this.state.companies.filter(el => el._id !== id)
    });
  };

  onEdit = id => {
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/companies/edit/' + id).then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
    });

    this.setState({
      companies: to be done
    });
  };

  companyList() {
    if (!this.state.searchTerm) {
      return this.state.companies.map(currentcompany => {
        return (
          <Company
            company={currentcompany}
            onDelete={this.onDelete}
            key={currentcompany._id}
          />
        );
      });
    } else {
      return this.state.companies
        .filter(company => {
          return company.companyName
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(this.state.searchTerm);
        })
        .map(matchingCompany => {
          return (
            <Company
              company={matchingCompany}
              onDelete={this.onDelete}
              key={matchingCompany._id}
            />
          );
        });
    }
  }

  onSearchCompanyName = e => {
    this.setState({
      searchTerm: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <br />
        <h2>Firmalar</h2>
        <hr />
        <this.CompanyModal />
        <hr />
        <Form>
          <FormControl
            placeholder="Firma Ara"
            onChange={this.onSearchCompanyName}
            value={this.state.searchTerm}
          ></FormControl>
        </Form>
        <br />

        <Table striped bordered hover>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Firma Adı</th>
              <th>Vergi Dairesi</th>
              <th>Vergi Numarası</th>
              <th>Eklenme Tarihi</th>
              <th>Düzenle</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{this.companyList()}</tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Companies;
```

View of Program:
[ScreenShot](https://ibb.co/BC5gpqs)

- It is a MERN Project:
- I am working on a web app that make user CRUD operations on Company model.
- I've done Get-Add-Delete operations but i am confused about the Update Operation.
- I want to use my CompanyModal(which is a bootstrap-modal to add companies) Component Modal for also editing companies.
- Could you please give hint or advice to do it? Actually my mind goes blank.

Comment: have you create delete api of nodejs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   const Company = props => (
      <tr>
        <td>{props.company.companyName}</td>
        <td>{props.company.taxOffice}</td>
        <td>{props.company.taxNumber}</td>
        <td>{props.company.date}</td>
        <td>
          <Button variant="danger" onClick={()=>handleDelete(props)}>Delete</Button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <Button variant="success" onClick={()=>handleEdit(props)}>Edit</Button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
```

Define your `handleDelete` function in from where you are passing data to `Company` component

```
handleDelete=(data)=>{
  // make api request to delete object by(data.id)
}
handleEdit=(data)=>{
 //make your model show to true
 // then set your data fiels to state.
 // then make your model show to false after updation
}
```

pass your `handleDelete` and `handleEdit` to `Company` component

```
    companyList() {
        return this.state.companies.map(currentcompany => {
          return <Company handleDelete={this.handleDelete} 
          company={currentcompany} key={currentcompany._id} 
          handleEdit={this.handleEdit}/>;
        });
      }
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But now i am confused with how can i use  the CompanyModal(using it for adding) for editing a company.

Comment: @ocyalcin i updated solution for your edit also...please accept/vote if answer is helpful for you... and let me know if need any other help.

Comment: Still cant understand how to reuse the add modal

Comment: hey i uploaded it to github [link](https://github.com/ocyyy/tracker_demo)

Comment: @ocyalcin there is not frontend code in your project. it's only backend code.

Comment: i uploaded it to codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/umut-tracker-jy9p9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one api endpoint like : `companies/delete/:id`

Then you can access your id as req.params.id and then perform delete operation

you can call this api onClick of your delete button

create onDelete function in your parent component and pass it to your child component as props

```
<Button 
   variant="danger" 
   onClick = { () => props.onDelete(props.company.id) } >
 Delete
</Button>
```

Comment: let me know if you have any problem.